# C# Reference result of method later in program

Tags: c#, methods

I'm looking to figure out how I could reference the result of an early method later in my code. For example, my code below allows the user to choose a character name. If, later on in the game, I want to reference the string charName, how would I do that? I think I may need to use a return command but hit errors trying that.

```
 static void chooseCharacterName() //Method allows the user to enter their name and will loop until user chooses 1 and accepts.
    {
        string charName;
        string areYouHappyWithThisName;
        UInt32 validName = 0;
        Console.Write("Please enter a character name: ");
        string charNameAsText = Console.ReadLine();
        charName = Convert.ToString(charNameAsText);
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen: " + charName);
        Console.WriteLine();
        while (true)
        {

            Console.Write("Do you want to keep this name? Type 1 for Yes, Type 2 for No. If No then choose again:  ");
            areYouHappyWithThisName = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!UInt32.TryParse(areYouHappyWithThisName, out validName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Please try again. Enter 1 for Yes and 2 for No");
            }
            else if (validName > 2 || validName < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Please try again. Enter 1 for Yes and 2 for No");
            }
            //else if (areYouHappyWithThisName == "2")
            else if(validName == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                chooseCharacterName(); //this method contains the whole routine
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Good luck " + charName + ", you're going to need it!");
                break;
            }
        break;
        }
    }
```

Thank you all for your help as always - Yurc

Comment: You say you've tried "to use a return command" but that you ran into errors doing so. Show your code for that,  attempt to build it, and tell us what errors you get.

Comment: Tried this: else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Good luck " + charName + ", you're going to need it!");
                    return charName;
                    //break;
                }
            break; and received error 'Program.chooseCharacterName()': not all code paths return a value

Comment: Yes, it's because `not all code patsh return a value`. You return a value ONLY in the else statement. You need to return a string no matter the situation. Ex: you return a null and check the returned value, or you return the name and also check to ensure it is not null.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, read through it carefully (not just the code) so you understand where you're going wrong rather than just copy/pasting code.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a field `static string chosenChar = null;` and when he makes his mind, set the `chosenChar` to the value he chose. This way, you'll have the string stored into a `static` field. To get it, simply use a getter (property, since it's C#, and make it read-only).

```
while(true)
{
    //do stuff
}
if(charName != null)
    this.staticStringVariableName = charName;
```

Add this in your function. `staticStringVariableName` should be a `static string staticStringVariableName = null;` where you can set whatever name you want, and you could simply assign its value like that.

Comment: @Yurconale, any update? Did it work or not, did it fix your problem or not?

Comment: Hi Simply, I might be missing a step. Giving your code a try and if I change  the method name from static string chooseCharacterName(); to static string chooseCharacterName = null; I get hit with 107 errors all over the program. Is there any chance you could elaborate more?

Comment: Wait, what? I said "add a static string variable!".

Comment: Field = variable. Method = function.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems in your code. First, your infinite while loop isn't infinite as it has a non-conditional break at the end, so it will never execute more than once and defeats the entire purpose of having a while loop. Second, if you're getting the error "Not all code paths return a value" you need to think about where you're placing your `return`. Placing it outside any nested code blocks and at the end of your function is one way to ensure that this happens. You also have recursion that has no deterministic stopping condition.

```
static string chooseCharacterName() //Method allows the user to enter their name and will loop until user chooses 1 and accepts.
{
    string charName;
    string areYouHappyWithThisName;
    UInt32 validName = 0;
    Console.Write("Please enter a character name: ");
    string charNameAsText = Console.ReadLine();
    charName = Convert.ToString(charNameAsText);
    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen: " + charName);
    Console.WriteLine();
    while (true)
    {

        Console.Write("Do you want to keep this name? Type 1 for Yes, Type 2 for No. If No then choose again:  ");
        areYouHappyWithThisName = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!UInt32.TryParse(areYouHappyWithThisName, out validName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again. Enter 1 for Yes and 2 for No");
        }
        else if (validName > 2 || validName < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again. Enter 1 for Yes and 2 for No");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Good luck " + charName + ", you're going to need it!");
            break; //leave this break here
        }
        //break; //I don't think you want this break
    }

    return charName;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jak, the second break was the only way I could figure out to stop the program from prompting me from entering 1 or 2 again if I chose to restart the method. In other words, if I accepted the name when first asked the method would end, if I said no and entered a new name it would ask me twice if I accepted before ending the program.

Comment: If I use your code, how do I call that specific string charName for later uses?

Comment: In the code that calls chooseCharacterName, you would do:
`char charName = chooseCharacterName();`

Comment: static void chooseAttributePoints()
        {
            string charName = chooseCharacterName();
            UInt32 attributePoints = 25;
            string inputStrength;
            string inputSpeed;

Comment: Hi Jak, did the above code to try and reference the name the user chose from the previous method and now it's just asking to re-enter a char name before choose attributes. Did i miss a step? Sorry, I've been coding for literally 3 weeks and am as new as it gets.

Comment: You need to remove the recursive call where indicated in the comments. In fact, remove that entire branch it isn't doing anything useful. Also, I made a mistake in that last comment `char charName` should be `string charName` I'll update the code in my answer to remove that branch